# Normal derivative for Laplace equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, finite-element-method

I am try to evaluate the Neumann boundary conditions for Laplace equation which define as: dy/dn, where n  the external normal vector to the boundary, I have:

```
ClearAll[y, x1, x2];
pde = D[D[y[x1, x2], x1], x1] + D[D[y[x1, x2], x2], x2];
bc = {y[x1, 1] == 1 + x1^2, y[x1, 2] == 4 + x1^2};
```

Neumann boundary condition is defined on the other sides of the square; i.e.,

`x1 = 1` or `x1 = 2`, `{x1, 1, 2}, {x2, 1, 2}`;

My question is how can I evaluate the normal derivative in the PDE for any domain, say, square, circle, triangular, etc.? Is there any function to do that?

Comment: Are you going to use the Neumann derivative in conjunction with the FEM capabilities of `NDSolve`? In that case, you should learn about `NeumannValue` because it works differently than you might think...

Comment: you have not said if you are using `DSolve` or `NDSolve`. As Henrik is saying, if you are using `NDSolve` with `NeumannValue`, then it takes care of all that for you for any boundary shape. See help on `NeumannValue`

Comment: Dear Henril and Nasser, many thanks for your response, I will read about NemannValue but my question is not to solve rather than just calculate the normal derivative in mathematica?

Comment: `calculate the normal derivative in mathematica?` you can google directional derivative and Mathematica. Here is a demo also https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DirectionalDerivativesAndTheGradient/ so you can examine the code.

Comment: Thank you Nasser, I still could not able to evaluate it.

Comment: "my question is not to solve rather than just calculate the normal derivative in mathematica?" Then how is this question related to those `pde`, `bc`, etc. in your question? Please be more specifc.